# how to get data from a view table(which has resource_full) from Google bigquery(google-cloud-ruby gem)

Tags: ruby, google-bigquery

I am working on Sinatra,ruby Application.

I need to get data from one view table which is in Google-BigQuery and I am using google-cloud-bigquery gem in my Application.

here is how am Querying the google-bigquery(ruby code)

```
bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new(<necessary credentials for the application>)
query = "select * from `dataset.table_name`  limit 10"
bigquery.query query  => #(this query will give me the exact output)
```

but, when I am querying without limit, like following

```
query = "select * from `dataset.table_name`"
bigquery.query query
```

I will get this kind of response.

```
Google::Cloud::InvalidArgumentError (resourcesExceeded: Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed)
```

so, here in this case how can I handle it. as, I need to get all the data from that table I shouldn't give any limit.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of querying whole table - you should use [`Tabledata: list`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list) API (or respective method in client of your choice)

Using List is free and also comes with paging so you can get whole table data page by page

Comment: Thank you for responding Mikhail Berlyant.

I have tried that API through API explorer and I got the following Response.
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Cannot list a table of type VIEW.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Cannot list a table of type VIEW.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
} 
can you please share me if you have any code sample to do this and also what will be the default PageToken Parameter value

Comment: You can list data from table only, not from view :o(

Comment: yeah, I will do in that way Mikhail Berlyant. Thank you.